# JS hover-like animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I am not really good in CSS animations/transitions and have no idea what of them exactly have to use to implement hover-like animation with JS.

I want to call animation when I change data to highlight it, then reset it back to default state, after like 0.5 seconds. And being able to do that many times to the same element (without refreshing page / hiding|showing it).

Comment: do you neccessarily, need to do it with JS?

Comment: and change what data? have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I am using VueJS, so I want to call animation start from JS to highlight that view changes in browser

Comment: I have tried to use VueJS transitions (but they work only when hiding\showing data) as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code

HTML

```
<div id="item">hover me</div>
```

CSS

```
#item{
   transition : all 0.5s ease-out;
   background : #fff;
   color      : #000;
}

.hovered{
   background : #000 !important;
   color      : #fff !important;
}
```

JS

```
item.onmouseenter = function(){
   this.classList.add('hovered');
}

item.onmouseleave = function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      this.classList.remove('hovered');
   }.bind(this),1000)
}
```

check out this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1ty551gL/

to get it working automatically on data change :

JS

```
function onchange(){

   item.classList.add('hovered');

   setTimeout(function(){
       item.classList.remove('hovered');
   },1000);

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! How can I activate it without mouse enter? I would like to activate it from function

Comment: please consider voting up and check marking this answer, what function do you need? please describe

Comment: `<div class="uk-background uk-padding-small uk-panel">
      {{status}}
</div>` - this is what in my HTML, and this is how I update my data in js: `if (...) {
            ...
            this.status = 'some new data'
            callAnimationHere()
          }`. I want to call animation right after I updated my data

Comment: instead of `item.onmouseenter` and `item.onmouseleave` - use `document.querySelector('.uk-background').onmouseenter` and `document.querySelector('.uk-background').onmouseleave` - or add an `id=""` to your div, and then you can reference it directly without using `document.querySelector`

Comment: I want it to work without any user input, it should be called each time automatically, after data is changed (code is above) How to do that?